# Search and replace using a regex in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, replace

How to do a search and replace with Sublime Text, so it finds `"(wildcard)"`?

I want to do a simple find and replace to get curly quotes, I expect that this can be done using regex.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to make curly quotes into straight quotes, then can you just replace `“`, `‘`, `”`, and `’` with `"`, `'`, `"`, and `'`, respectively? But maybe that is not your aim. You should be able to use the curly quotes "literally" in your regex, *e.g.*

```
“(.*?)”
```

**EDIT:**

Ah, so you want to convert straight quotes to curly quotes. In that case, try replacing

```
"([^"]*)"
```

with

```
“$1”
```

Comment: Guess I framed the question wrong, I wanted to replace normal quotes with curly ones.